# Basura en vector

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando leer un archivo byte por byte e ir cargando cada byte como un elemento del vector, pero por alguna extraña razón los dos primeros elementos del vector me aparecen como caracteres extraños(basura).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

void Cifrado(std::string nombre) 
{
    std::ifstream archivo;
    archivo.open(nombre.c_str(),std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<char>bites;

    if(!archivo)
    {
        std::cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo: "<<nombre<<std::endl;
        return;
    }

    char bite;

    while(!archivo.eof() && archivo.get(bite))
    {
        bites.push_back(bite);
    }

    for(unsigned int b = 0; b <= bites.size(); b++)
    {
        std::cout<<bites[b]<<std::endl;
    }

    std::cout<<bites.size()<<std::endl;

    archivo.close();

}


int main()
{
    Cifrado("texto.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

El archivo texto.txt contiene una cadena que dice así: Esto es una prueba.
Pero cuando lo muestro por pantalla me lo imprime así: ╗┐Esto es una prueba.

Comment: Comprueba la codificación del archivo, es posible que sea [UTF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) con [BOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark_.28BOM.29) y los caracteres extraños sean el BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cómo comento [PaperBirdMaster](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2742/paperbirdmaster) se trata del [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) que contiene el fichero al principio.

Para leer bien siempre el fichero independientemente de si tiene BOM o no podrías eliminar los 3 primeros carácteres (no guardarlos) si estos son:

- ufefff - Si lees todo a la vez
- EF BB BF - Si lees byte a byte (tu caso)

Comment: pss pss.... lo comentó PaperbirdMaster.... tranquilo, no eres el primero que nos confunde :D

Comment: @PakoLordPakus vaya liada... gracias por el aviso!

Comment: Tranquilo, lo he visto de casualidad, leyendo rápido ni lo ves

Comment: Opté por eliminar los 3 caracteres, gracias a todos.

Comment: Creo que la solución debería ser cambiar la codificación del archivo (no ingnorar los datos iniciales) ¿qué sentido tiene un archivo con datos **binarios** con codificación de **texto**?.